# toolbar disappear at rotation ipad project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I added uittolbar at design time , but I noticed that it disappear at landscape mode

how to fix that , I develop ipad application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the toolbar's [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6). This defines the behavior of the view in response to the superview's frame change. If you've done this programmatically, it will be `UIViewAutoresizingMaskNone` by default. You will have to set them appropriately.